# Pick a colored marble, but you may pick again with a certain probability. What's the probability that a certain marble has been picked k times?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Imagine there is a bowl with 10 marbles of which 4 are blue, 3 are green, 2 are red, and 1 is yellow.
You now may pick a random marble and put it back into the bowl. If you picked a blue marble, you may pick again with a chance of $p_{blue} = 0.5$. If you picked a green marble, you may pick again with a chance of $p_{green} = 0.25$. If it was a red marble, the chance to pick again is $p_{red} = 0.1$. And lastly, if it was a yellow marble, you may not pick another marble.

Now, what I generally want to know is: **What is the probability that a marble of a certain color has been picked $k$ times?**

Let's say we want to know with what probability a red marble has been picked exactly 1 time. What is the probability?

I struggle to even write down this probability function. Maybe Markov chains can help here?

Comment: I would think recursive methods are best.  The first draw either gives you the desired color or it doesn't, and either way you have some chance of continuing the game, or it is over.  Writing that out gives you a simple recursion.

Comment: Note:  the simple recursive method I sketched is intended to compute the probability that you get *at least* $k$ instances of the given color.  If, instead, you meant *exactly* $k$, then note that $P(X=k)=P(X≥k)-P(X≥k+1)$.